# JavaScript after creating input element, value not shown on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, input, web-storage

This is my JavaScript code to create a form with multiple "input" tags.

```
function getStorageValues(){

if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined")

  {

var myform=document.createElement("FORM");
myform.type = "post";
myform.action = "";
myform.name = "myform";
document.body.appendChild(myform);

for (var i = 0; i < sessionStorage.length; i++) { 
var myinput=document.createElement("INPUT");
myinput.value = sessionStorage.getItem(i);    //something wrong with this???
myinput.name = "tag" + i;


document.myform.appendChild(myinput);
 }
}
```

However, when the form is created, I do not see the "value" attributes of any of created input fields when I do "inspect element" on browser. All I can see is:

```
<input name="tag0">
<input name="tag1">
<input name="tag2">
... ando so on ...
```

Any ideas where the "value" attribute has gone? And how to get it shown there? I can see the value inside the input field, though! But I need to have it in the code too!

P.S. Im sorry, I cannot create fiddle demo, as this is using web storage. Pasting full code is just too much.

Comment: Where's the `input type`?

Comment: @MelanciaUK will it make any sense if it was there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with the setAttribute method ?

```
myinput.setAttribute("value", sessionStorage.getItem(i));
```

Edit : you can also try to join it with an empty string in order to change the type :

```
myinput.value = "" + sessionStorage.getItem(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

`sessionStorage` can't be accessed like that using a numeric key. `getItem` requires a string. To get the key and access the value, you can do this:

```
myinput.value = sessionStorage.getItem(sessionStorage.key(i));
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion, but this got me the same result as I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
myinput.setAttribute('value', sessionStorage.getItem(i))
```

I tried it it's working for me!